# Angular router resolver not waiting before switching component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm getting the data from the resolver fine in my component, but it's not waiting before array is fully populated from external API to then switch to the component. So i get a empty screen and then after a few seconds the data is shown.

As soon as I click the submit button with routerlink to the component it switches to said component.

Resolver:

```
@Injectable()
export class BeerResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private beerResolver: BeerResolver,private router: Router) {
  }

  resolve() {
    return this.beerResolver.getPosts().pipe(delay(500))
  }
}
```

Service:

```
getPosts() {

    const obs = of(this.beerQR);
    obs.subscribe(val => console.log( val),
      error => console.log("error"),
      () => console.log("complete"))
  return obs
  }
```

Component:

```
async ngOnInit() {
 this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
       console.log('Check route resolver data')
       console.log(data)
       this.newArr=data
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve component behaviour according to user expectations, I would suggest you to show spinner in your component template.

```
//ts    
isLoading = false;
ngOnInit() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this.route.data
    .pipe(finalize(() => this.isLoading = false))
    .subscribe(data => this.newArr = data)
}


//html
<ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading; else: spinner">
  <!--show content-->
</ng-container>

<ng-container #spinner">
  <!--show spinner-->
</ng-container>
```